# jQuery get selected index of radio buttons

Tags: jquery, indexing, radio-button, selectedindex

I am fully aware that this question has seen numerous variants, so please examine it thoroughly before down-voting it as I'm certain that a clear solution will help many others also.

I have a series of radio buttons being dynamically generated as part of a loop through database records. One radio per record in HTML. Each radio button is being assigned an array index value of the record id;

```
<input type="radio" id="use_msg_id[1]" value="1" />
<input type="radio" id="use_msg_id[2]" value="2" />
<input type="radio" id="use_msg_id[3]" value="3" />
<input type="radio" id="use_msg_id[4]" value="4" />
```

When a user clicks, let's say, on the radio button with use_msg_id[3], I need jQuery to be able to gather that index value for me. I know there's a way to do it, but have not been searching the right terms to find the proper solution.

Thanks.

Comment: If indexes are always going to be sorted in that order, then you could use `index()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `regex` to extract number

```
$(':radio').change(function(){
    var index = $(this).val().match(/\d+/);
})
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/6VyK8/)

Comment: For `index` I believe he refeers to the number between brackets in the `id` tag, therefore this solution only works if that number is related with the order in which they appear in the DOM.

Comment: That would be correct, I need that number in the brackets.

Comment: @Satpal - That's perfect! It returns ["2", index: 0, input: "2"] for the one I clicked on. I should be able to extract the id from that result. Thank you. :)

Comment: Indeed! @Alvaro, thank you for bringing that clarity to this question. I'm certain this will help many others out greatly.

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
 parseInt($(this).attr('id').replace(/use_msg_id[/, '').replace(/]/,''));
```

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
var id = this.id.substr(this.id.indexOf("["), this.id.indexOf("]"))
parseInt(id);
```

Comment: Additionally, this answer actually has brought solution to another aspect of the same process I am working through. So, thank you for this as well!